QGIS calculated area output as CSV
I have used the graphical modeler to extract polygons. I calculate the areas of each polygon in the attribut table.
Since I have multiple layers, I do not want to use the  function Field Statistic for each layer.
Is there a way to create a CSV  or something similiar in a specific folder with the calculated areas of all desired layers ?

Calculate the area first then export the layer(s) Right click -> Export -> Save Features As...  comma separated value.

Probably, using Batch
